# Is there a clipboard (copy and paste) manager with stack or ring hotkey functionality?

Tags: clipboard, clipboard-manager

I'm looking for a clipboard manager (of which I know there are many like ClipIt, CopyQ, etc) but I'm looking for something specific: I want to be able to copy multiple items separately (which will put them all into the clipboard manager's history) and then paste them all somewhere without having to use the mouse to go to the manager menu to select them to paste. I want to be able to paste with hotkeys or some kind of way to navigate through the clipboard history as a stack or ring.

Does this exist?

Answer (score 1):

Parcellite. It captures the clipboard, <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>Alt</kbd>-<kbd>H</kbd> to bring its stack up, then select to paste to clipboard . you can only select individually though. I have noted <kbd>ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>alt</kbd>-<kbd>s</kbd> brings up a save as for history, but that doesn't work for me here... but in the top bar click on the P parcellite  icon for save as.

Comment: see parcellite preferences hotkeys, ctrl-alt-p for savas menu. no mice required.